# How to merge many calls of wcf service in one

Tags: c#, wcf, caching

I have a site with many users (asp.net+c#). The site calls a very slow wcf service. How can I merge all of calls in one? What technology/method/idea should I use? Users  shouldn't be lock for long time. The site cache the service result, but once in hour it flushes cache and all users call wcf service in one moment.

More information:
After cache is flushed the site asks service. If all users of ask service (there is a lot of users) , the service will die. Is it possible to do only 1 call to service from 10000 users? Ok, the site use cache, but the service response time is for about 30-60 second. If all users asks service by the one time during 30 second, it will be 10000 calls to service. And it will die. Should I use something like "lock" ? But I don't want to lock all site users.

Comment: You question is very unclear. What do you mean by *How can I merge all of calls in one* ? Are you talking about some kind of throttling behavior?

Comment: Hello Tom, first, I'm very sorry for my bad english and not clear question.

Comment: After cache is flushed the site asks service. If all users of ask service (there is a lot of users) , the service will die. Is it possible to do only 1 call to service from 10000 users? Ok, the site use cache, but the service response time is for about 30-60 second. If all users asks service by the one time during 30 second, it will be 10000 calls to service. And it will die. Should I use something like "lock" ? But I don't want to lock all site users.

Comment: How service handle 10000 calls while it has a cache? In same way it should handle 10000 calls while it's making new cache. First of 10000 calls make job (prepare new cache), all others 9999 wait this cache and do nothing. As cache ready they read it. You need some lock on cache preparations

Comment: And, of course, service cann't control when and how often clients call it

Comment: Hello, @Ivan. There is a part of code `code` if (locker != null){
 lock (locker){
  result = cache.Get(cacheKey);
  if (result == null){
   try{
    service.Open();
    result = service.GetPageInfo(request);
    service.Close();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
    service.Abort();
    WebSiteLogger.Logger.Error(WebSiteLogger.EventName.ServiceCall, ex, new {request});
   }
   Add(cache, cacheKey, result, cacheTime, sliding);
  }
 }
}
else
{
 result = func();
 Add(cache, cacheKey, result, cacheTime, sliding);
}`code` It's not compile, I've union some methods in one.

Comment: If cache will flush in onу moment this part  "lock (locker)" - is not good idea. All users of site will be lock and wait for result from service. I have a dream to know a better decision. But if there is no such decision, I'll use callback and lock. Thank you. I'm very appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no data to answer on request, then you have to load it. And while it loading all will wait because while it loading there is nothing to send back

So you have to make a send-back data always ready. How can you do it? Update your cache at the background mode (prepare new cache before flush previous and update, pereiodically update...)

Another approach is not to wait at client while wcf is finished his work (async call). Make two methods: one start some long work, second receive a long work results.

Then you have two techiiques:push and pull notifications.
Clint should sometimes call second method asking a result, or wcf call client when finish his work.